# Joining sfc objects and assigning categorical attribute using maximum overlapping area

Tags: join, attributes, r-sf

Imagine the following sfc objects

```
zone_A <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 2, ymax = 2)))
zone_B <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 2, xmax = 2, ymax = 4)))
Zones <- st_as_sf(data.frame(class = c("A", "B"),c(zone_A, zone_B)))
st_crs(Zones) <- "WGS84"

feat_X <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 0.5, ymin = 1.25, xmax = 1.5, ymax = 3.5)))
feat_Y <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 0.1, ymin = 0.5, xmax = 0.5, ymax = 2.2)))
feat_Z <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = 1.5, ymin = 2.5, xmax = 1.9, ymax = 3.5)))
feat <- st_as_sf(data.frame(name = c("X", "Y", "Z"),c(feat_X, feat_Y, feat_Z)))
st_crs(feat) <- "WGS84"
```

looking like this:

[ggplot showing to superimposed layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXKEl.png)

My task is to join these two layers and assign the categorical variable `class` from the `Zones` object to each feature of the `feat` object. If a feature is overlapping two zones, the the overlapping area should serve as a criterion to assign which class to assign.

While this can be pretty easily done with unambiguous overlays (*like Z int the example*) using st_join, the function creates two features if a feature crosses two features of the the Zones object (*like X and Y*). Here, I seek for a solution that calculates the area of the intersections, compares the areas and assigns the `class` attribute of the bigger intersect to the entire feature. Idealy this should work for bigger sfc objects with multiple polygons (maybe iterating through all ambiguous) polygons.

This would be something similar to `st_interpolate_aw`, but with categorical instead of numerical data. I don't know of any ready-to-use function that would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `st_join` function has the argument `largest`. if you set `largest=TRUE`, it will "return x features augmented with the fields of y that have the largest overlap with each of the features of x". see here - https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_join.html.

Is this what you need?